# Is the BEM methodology in the large project used correctly

Tags: web-development, html, css

I am creating SCSS for the large project, I decided to use BEM methodology. I will have a lot of containers. I have question about BEM and about best practices.

My current code:

```
.footer {
    &__intro {
        margin-bottom: 5em;
    }
    &__menu {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-items: centre
    }
    &__menu-item {
        &:not(:last-of-type) {
            margin-right: 1rem;
        }
    }
}
```

And HTML structure

```
<div class=“footer”>
    <div class=“footer__intro”>
        <ul class=“footer__menu”>
            <li class=“footer__menu-item”>
                <span>some text</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

So I’m wondering if it’s good practice - I’m thinking about something, that will be easy to read for next developers working on that project. Is example shown above better than e.g.

- `.footer__menu > .footer__menu__item`
- `.footer__intro__menu > .footer__intro__menu-item`

I want to create universally understandable code that will be easy to read and develop by others.

Comment: A good practive for in any document, code, posts, whatever, is not to assume everyone knows what certain cryptic abbreviations mean (and also not to assume that only persons who might know the abbreviations can answer this question).

Comment: I'm assuming this is about [Block, Element, Modifier](https://en.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/).

Comment: To the down-voters: this question has a concrete code example asking if this is a correct implementation of a design pattern or methodology. We have dozens of questions like this that are well-received in C#, Java, C++, and their ilk. This question is perfectly on-topic for this community.

Comment: This was also migrated from a different community, so let's give the OP some time to respond.

Answer (score 4):

Not everything needs a class. Furthermore, words like "item" are not a modifier. They are *another* element. A modifier would indicate some change in state, such as "deleted" or "included/excluded". The state being some business-related term that cannot be expressed using plain old HTML.

In your case, the `footer__intro__menu-item` class assumes that `item` is a state, when in fact it is an element. Instead, consider removing that class and using `footer__intro__menu > li` as the selector for styles.

The Block-Element-Modifier naming convention aims at reducing style collisions between components. You can take this too far when you start using classes in use cases where an HTML tag, or CSS pseudo-class provides the same granularity and style isolation without resorting to classitus.

Comment: One good approach I like is to have one root element and few children. All the elements that do not have a class can be accessed with combinators, mainly if you use semantic HTML.